# Newtonsoft JSON serialize list in list

Tags: serialization, json.net, uwp, entity-framework-core

I am using a ef core database in my UWP app and have some issues serializing a list containing a list with Newtonsoft JSON.

For a minimal example consider the UWP tutorial from [microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/get-started/uwp/getting-started) with the following code

```
public class Blog
{
    public int BlogId { get; set; }
    public string Url { get; set; }

    public List<Post> Post { get; set; }
}

public class Post
{
    public int PostId { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Content { get; set; }

    public int BlogId { get; set; }
    public Blog Blog { get; set; }
}

public class BloggingContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Blog> Blogs { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Post> Posts { get; set; }

    protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
    {
        optionsBuilder.UseSqlite("Filename=minexample.db");
    }
}
```

when I now want to serialize some data the following way:

```
using (var db = new BloggingContext())
{
    var dbPost = db.Blogs.Include(x => x.Post).ToList();
    var serialized = JSONClass.Serialize(dbPost);
}
```

I get an error of type `System.StackOverflowException` in `mscorlib.ni.dll` that I enter an infinity loop. As user alanh mentioned in the comments, this behavior can be fixed with setting `ReferenceLoopHandling` to `ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore` in `JsonSerializerSettings`.

**I would prefer to just store the `ID` of each Post as `List<int>` instead of `List<Post>` when serializing the Blog.**

Why serializing, if a database is given? I want to share specific database entries and need to serialize them. Also I consider doing this for synchronization with `OneDrive`, so there is no clash, when editing different database entries on different devices at different times (single user).

Comment: JsonSerializerSettings, referenceloophandling = ignore http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_ReferenceLoopHandling.htm

Comment: wow, I was trying `JsonSerializerSettings` too, but with `ReferenceLoopHandling.Serialize`. So now I can serialize the whole thing. Is there also a way to just serialize the `PostId` as alias to a post?

Comment: @user3079834 - can you [edit] your question to explain your new requirement as explained in your most recent comment?

Comment: @alanh is right on infinite loop. When you have navigations in both direction for a relationship, JSON serialize goes to infinite loop because navigation properties keep pointing to each other.

Comment: @dbc I updated the question.

Answer (score 1):

Adding this line of code into your Startup class, prevents your loop problem

```
 services.AddMvc().AddJsonOptions(options => options.SerializerSettings.ReferenceLoopHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore);
```

Then you can use the `[JsonIgnore]` attribute for all those properties that you don't want to be serialized.

Or you can implement your own serializer by extending the `JsonConverter` class and implementing your own `WriteJson, ReadJson` and `CanConvert` methods as shown in here:

[implement your own serializer](http://blog.maskalik.com/asp-net/json-net-implement-custom-serialization/)